# How to know which packages are not in use and can be unistalled?

Tags: linux-mint, package-management

I've got an upgrade of Linux Mint 19.2 "Tina" and I've installed some packages when I tried to find out how to fix an error. It was an handful of packages and they might not have anything to do with the error.

Now I don't know which ones are to be uninstalled, because some of them might already been installed previously and might be in use.

Is there a way to find out which ones could be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install deborphan
```

Once  installed, run: `deborphan`, this should show you the unused packages. To finally remove them, type `sudo orphaner`.

Hope this helps :)